# Run an executable .jar file and confirm running prior to Windows login occurs to hide access to Windows Desktop

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

I wish to run an executable .jar file before the windows login screen is ever shown to the user so that when windows logs in to display the desktop, the user is first shown the full-screen view that my .jar displays without ever seeing the windows login screen/windows home screen.

To start off, (I have configured Windows to perform an automatic login on startup/restart to a non Admin User profile. I want to display my .jar UI instead of the Windows desktop for the Non Admin User only).

To Achieve Automatic Log In I Did the Following:

```
I did Run> "control userpasswords2" 
checked "Users must enter a user name and password to use the computer"
added Non Admin user as a standard user with no password (no Administrator privileges)
I made sure the Non Admin user was selected and unchecked "Users must enter     
a user name and password to use the computer" then hit Apply. This caused the     
"Automatically Log On" window to pop up and I made sure the Non Admin user with 
no password was the selected user.
```

My .jar is configured to be the top most window when it is open (and is non close-able unless an admin keyboard is used) and as such, when my .jar is open and running this effectively renders the desktop non clickable (which is what I want to accomplish). The user should never be able to click to windows desktop even on restart and should only have access to click on my .jar's User Interface.

How would you suggest to accomplish this?

I have tried:

```
Run gpedit.msc (Win+R -> gpedit.msc)
Go to "Computer Configuration" -> Windows Setting -> Scripts (Startup/shutdown)->
Go to Startup properties -> Show Files -> Placed my .bat and .jar inside
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup then closed that directory and 
in Startup Properties Add-> Script Name -> mybatFile.bat
```

The .bat file is located in the same directory `C:\NonAdmin` as my .jar and contains the following:

```
java -jar %~dp0myjarfile.jar %*
```

**Note: My .bat does successfully launch my .jar when it is double clicked**

but I havent been able to get my .jar to launch on startup so that the desktop is hidden behind it when user logon occurs automatically to the Non Admin User.

So I tried:

```
Log into Non Admin User > Put my .jar in C:\NonAdminProgram folder > Right Click > 
Create Shortcut > Press Windows + R keys > shell:startup > Explorer window showing > 
C:\Users\NonAdmin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup > 
Drag Shortcut of .jar to this directory
```

But this launches the .jar after the login screen is displayed so the user briefly sees the login screen before my .jar takes over and displays its UI on top. (NOT EXACTLY WHAT I WANT) But close...

I want to make sure that the User never sees the Desktop on a restart or computer startup/boot - The first thing they see should be my .jar's UI instead - Every Time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and works on windows 10:

1. With a text editor, type `@echo off taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` and save it as a .bat or .file, e.g. killwinexplorer.bat
2. Open Start menu, type Task Scheduler and then press ENTER.
3. Click Action, and then click Create Task…
4. Click Change User or Group… button to select the user to run the
   task.
5. Select "Run only when user is logged on".
6. On Triggers tab, click New… button.
7. Pull down the "Begin the task" menu, and then click At log on.
8. Select Specific user.
9. Click OK.
10. On Actions tab, click New… button.
11. Click Browse… button and then
    locate the batch script you previously save and click Ok.
12. Log on with the selected user to test.

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b44f3310-774d-48a4-ad8f-3ec54a7c08b9/prevent-windows-explorer-from-starting?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: I wish I could try this, I followed the following tutorial:

http://jaredheinrichs.com/how-to-turn-a-windows-7-pc-into-a-kiosk.html

and now even in Administrator mode I cannot run any programs whatsoever, cannot run system restore, and cannot even edit the registry in safe mode with cmd prompt. 

I can run regedit but cannot make the changes to the registry to re-enable the permissions to run programs. Not sure what to do...

Comment: *Note I just fixed it but I had to use the windows startup boot menu to restore to factory default to fix... Ughh, I Will try the above in a bit here once I reinstall everything

Comment: That method only disable explorer (windows desktop). Then you need to start the jar. I think you could use the same batch script that the scheduled task runs to call your script and start it.